# How to make seperate dataframes to store the given values based on conditions from excel

Tags: python

I have an excel file imported and then converted as a dataframe I need some help with regarding on how to go about making different dataframes by seperating it based on conditions like based on the cardtype given and further classification based on above 2000 and below 2000[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsCsH.png)

I know it might sound simple for many my apologies in advance since i am new to it i do understand the logic but the coding doesnt fit right through my mind so i expect some guidance or solutions thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your dataframe is defined under `df` and the column of card types is named `cardtype`.
Here's a simple example of filtering/showing only the rows where RuPay is the cardtype:

```
df_rupay_card = df[df["cardtype"]=="RuPay"]
```

Same thing with filtering based on above or below 2000